# Improving usage of C++ vector access

Tags: c++, performance, qt, profiling

I am writing currently an importer for Labplot to support BLF files. The importer works fine, but when looking at the performance it is visible that there is a lot of room to improve. It is visible that adding the data to the datacontainer consumes the most of the computational power. I tried already for testing using std::vector, but it has not that big impact.
I am not able to use a static array, because the actual number of messages is unknown (only upper limit is known), because if the dbcParser is not able to parse the message it will be skipped. So at the end of the import I have to resize the array.

Are there any recomandations how to improve the performance of the code?

[image: Profiling]

Definition of v: `QVector<const Vector::BLF::ObjectHeaderBase*> v;`

```cpp
bool firstMessageValid = false;
for (const auto ohb : v) {
    int id;
    std::vector<double> values;
    if (ohb->objectType == Vector::BLF::ObjectType::CAN_MESSAGE) {
        const auto message = reinterpret_cast<const Vector::BLF::CanMessage*>(ohb);
        id = message->id;
        m_dbcParser.parseMessage(message->id, message->data, values);
    } else if (ohb->objectType == Vector::BLF::ObjectType::CAN_MESSAGE2) {
        const auto message = reinterpret_cast<const Vector::BLF::CanMessage2*>(ohb);
        id = message->id;
        m_dbcParser.parseMessage(message->id, message->data, values);
    } else
        return 0;

    if (values.size() == 0) {
        // id is not available in the dbc file, so it is not possible to decode
        DEBUG("Unable to decode message: " << id);
        continue;
    }

    uint64_t timestamp;
    timeInNS = getTime(ohb, timestamp);
    if (convertTimeToSeconds) {
        double timestamp_seconds;
        if (timeInNS)
            timestamp_seconds = (double)timestamp / pow(10, 9); // TimeOneNans
        else
            timestamp_seconds = (double)timestamp / pow(10, 5); // TimeTenMics

        m_DataContainer.setData<double>(0, message_index, timestamp_seconds);
    } else
        m_DataContainer.setData<qint64>(0, message_index, timestamp);

    if (firstMessageValid) {
        const auto startIndex = idIndexTable.value(id) + 1; // +1 because of time
        for (std::vector<double>::size_type i = 1; i < startIndex; i++) {
            const auto prevValue = m_DataContainer.data<double>(i, message_index - 1);
            m_DataContainer.setData<double>(i, message_index, prevValue);
        }
        for (std::vector<double>::size_type i = startIndex; i < startIndex + values.size(); i++) {
            m_DataContainer.setData<double>(i, message_index, values.at(i - startIndex));
        }
        for (std::vector<double>::size_type i = startIndex + values.size(); i < m_DataContainer.size(); i++) {
            const auto prevValue = m_DataContainer.data<double>(i, message_index - 1);
            m_DataContainer.setData<double>(i, message_index, prevValue);
        }
    } else {
        const auto startIndex = idIndexTable.value(id) + 1; // +1 because of time
        for (std::vector<double>::size_type i = 1; i < startIndex; i++) {
            m_DataContainer.setData<double>(i, message_index, 0);
        }
        for (std::vector<double>::size_type i = startIndex; i < startIndex + values.size(); i++) {
            m_DataContainer.setData<double>(i, message_index, values.at(i - startIndex));
        }
        for (std::vector<double>::size_type i = startIndex + values.size(); i < m_DataContainer.size(); i++) {
            m_DataContainer.setData<double>(i, message_index, 0);
        }
        firstMessageValid = true;
    }
    message_index++;
}
```

```cpp
struct DataContainer {
        void clear();

        template<class T>
        void appendVector(QVector<T>* data, AbstractColumn::ColumnMode cm) {
            m_dataContainer.push_back(data);
            m_columnModes.append(cm);
        };

        template<class T>
        void setData(int indexDataContainer, int indexData, T value) {
            auto* v = static_cast<QVector<T>*>(m_dataContainer.at(indexDataContainer));
            v->operator[](indexData) = value;
        }

        template<class T>
        T data(int indexDataContainer, int indexData) {
            auto* v = static_cast<QVector<T>*>(m_dataContainer.at(indexDataContainer));
            return v->at(indexData);
        }

        int size() const;
        const QVector<AbstractColumn::ColumnMode> columnModes() const;

        /*!
         * \brief dataContainer
         * Do not modify outside as long as DataContainer exists!
         * \return
         */
        std::vector<void*> dataContainer() const;
        AbstractColumn::ColumnMode columnMode(int index) const;
        const void* datas(int index) const;
        bool resize(uint32_t) const;

    private:
        QVector<AbstractColumn::ColumnMode> m_columnModes;
        std::vector<void*> m_dataContainer; // pointers to the actual data containers
    };
```

#### Edit

Before the loop I resize every vector to the absolute maximum number of messages.

```cpp
if (convertTimeToSeconds) {
    auto* vector = new QVector<double>();
    vector->resize(message_counter);
    m_DataContainer.appendVector<double>(vector, AbstractColumn::ColumnMode::Double);
} else {
    auto* vector = new QVector<qint64>();
    vector->resize(message_counter);
    m_DataContainer.appendVector<qint64>(vector, AbstractColumn::ColumnMode::BigInt); // BigInt is qint64 and not quint64!
}
for (int i = 0; i < vectorNames.length(); i++) {
    auto* vector = new QVector<double>();
    vector->resize(message_counter);
    m_DataContainer.appendVector(vector, AbstractColumn::ColumnMode::Double);
}
```

During parsing I discard messages if I am not able to parse them, therefore `message_index <= message_counter`. So when having 100k messages, but I parse only 50k of them, I have to resize the array at the end to not waste memory.

```cpp
m_DataContainer.resize(message_index);
```

#### Edit2

Replacing

```cpp
auto* v = static_cast<QVector<T>*>(m_dataContainer.at(indexDataContainer));
v->operator[](indexData) = value;
```

by

```cpp
static_cast<QVector<T>*>(m_dataContainer.at(indexDataContainer))->operator[](indexData) = value;
```

and replacing

```cpp
auto* v = static_cast<QVector<T>*>(m_dataContainer.at(indexDataContainer));
return v->at(indexData);
```

by

```cpp
return static_cast<QVector<T>*>(m_dataContainer.at(indexDataContainer))->at(indexData);
```

brought about 20%. I thought it will be optimized out at -O2 but was not.

With -O2 moving from QVector to std::vector was again an improvement of around 25%

Comment: if you do know the maximum elements then you can use an array with fixed size.

Comment: yes but if I decrease the array afterwards it is not possible or do you think to copy them afterwards into a new array?

Comment: Any question concerning the speed of C++ must be accompanied by the compiler used, compiler version used, and the options used to build your application, namely the optimization settings.  If you are timing a debug or unoptimized build, the timings you are showing us are meaningless.

Comment: what do you mean with "decrease the array" ? You can use it like you use the vector, just that it has fixed capacity and size has to be managed manually. Not saying that it would be faster, its a tradeoff. Just trying to understand why you exclude it as option

Comment: Also, if Visual C++ is the compiler that is being used, note that `std::vector` has iterator checking for debug builds, slowing the code down, in some cases, by a huge factor.  This is why stating compiler and compiler options are important if questions are asked concerning the speed of a C++ program.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I added some more information to the description. At the end I resize the vector to match the parsed numbers of messages

Comment: `auto* vector = new QVector<double>();` -- Why are you creating a vector on the heap?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks for the hint. Currently clang with -O0 optimization is used. I will try std::vector with a higher optimization.

Comment: @Wuizl FYI -- `std::vector<void*> m_dataContainer;` -- If you had templatized `DataContainer`, i.e. `template <typename T> DataContainer { ... };`, then that vector could have been `std::vector<T> m_dataContainer;`, thus making it typesafe, as well as not needing to use pointers.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie this is because labplot assigns the vectors than to another container which is then used to draw the data.

Comment: 1) use `std::vector`. 2) take advantage of `std::vector::reserve`. 3) make sure you are compiling with optimizations enabled (also known as "release build").

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie but this is only possible if all vectors T have the same datatype. The first "row" might be double or long int and the others are doubles

Comment: @Wuizl -- I think you have memory leaks to worry about if you're going to go that route.  When it comes time to `delete`, how do you know what type to cast the `void *` back to so that the `delete` is correct?   I still claim that this could be templatized so that using `void *` is not necessary, it's just that you didn't investigate it fully enough.

Comment: _"Currently clang with -O0 optimization is used."_ Note that profiling unoptimized builds typically does not make any sense.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the dataContainer contains this datatype vector m_columnModes. This can be used to determine which type it has and deleting it correclty

Comment: There is no guarantee at all that resizing a vector to a smaller size will reclaim any memory.  Since doing so would make the complexity of resize() linear, it is quite certain that most STL implementation of resize will not reclaim memory.

Comment: @Wuizl *I have to resize the array at the end to not waste memory.* -- `resize()` will not do this.  If anything, and even this isn't guaranteed, is to `swap()` the contents of the vector into a smaller vector, or call [shrink_to_fit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit).  And again, that doesn't guarantee that any memory will be freed.

Comment: If you believe that the code works correctly, consider presenting your work (with its unit tests) in a more-complete fashion over at [codereview.se].  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.  Before you do that, make sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778) first, as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *does*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".

Comment: @DanielLangr I did the test again with -O2 and a big improvement of around 20% was to replace creating of the vector and accessing directly. Changing to std::vector was again an improvement of around 25%

Comment: Not performance-related but avoid pointers. Use smart pointers, or references wherever possible.

Comment: Thanks I will consider it, the problem is that the underlying architecture is using raw pointer, so it is not easy to change